# Table view not rendering correctly when I downsize it and it scrolls

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am working with a table view in Xcode that contains customs cells with a textfield element in them. If my table is expanded out to where a scroll isn't required then it works perfectly, but I am trying to have my table scroll to the next cell down once the user hits return so that it can be smaller.

The scrolling down on return part is actually working fine, the problem is that depending on how small I make the table view, it will replace a variable number of the cells below textField.text element with the user input that was added into a previous cell. I have no idea why this is happening.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell
    cell.id = indexPath.item
    cell.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.n.tag = indexPath.item

    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show your "cellForRowAt" implementation? That's likely a spot where a culprit is hidden.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell
        cell.id = indexPath.item
        cell.tag = indexPath.item
        cell.n.tag = indexPath.item
        return cell
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with an answer based off of your answers, so thank you very much and here it is.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->          UITableViewCell {
        print("Text field cell for row at")
        let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell

        if firstTable < numP{
            cell.n.text = nil
            cell.firstTime=true
            cell.n.tag = indexPath.row
            return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.n.text = names[indexPath.row]
            cell.n.tag = indexPath.row
            return cell
        }
        }
```

In my code the variable "firstTable" is incremented (in another function) each time user input is added until it reaches the total amount of inputs it's supposed to (based of previous views input). Inside the "if" it is using blank cells with the text value reset to nil to collect user input, but once firstTable > # supposed to be in array, the "else"  section is used to render the table using the elements from the array of user input to populate the cells.

Answer (score 0):

There is no resetting of `textField` values in your current implementation of `cellForRowAt`. Once user enters a text in one of the cells, it stays there and since cells keep being reused, it looks like text is just randomly appearing around.

User entered values must be stored somewhere. E.g. have a dictionary `var userInput = [Int: String]()`. Add `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol to your controller and implement the following:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textField.text as? NSString)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    userInput[textField.tag] = newText // store entered text

    return true
}
```

Then just update `cellForRowAt` with it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell
    cell.id = indexPath.item
    cell.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.n.tag = indexPath.item

    // update cell's textfield text
    cell.textField.delegate = self
    cell.textField.tag = indexPath.item
    cell.textField.text = userInput[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Currently I am storing user input into an array of strings, and that part is working fine, the problem is that I want the user to be able to scroll through the entire table (after entering all inputs) and change them. I have it working where it finds the element in the array and replaces it, but I need all the names to be shown in the cells for them to choose which one to actually replace. I guess my question is, once I implement the above, how do I populate all the cells in the table with the elements of the array I put the inputs into (after they enter all of them of course)?

Comment: @LoydStewart Not entirely sure I unterstand. "Populating all the cells" is happening right there in the `cellForRowAt` method. It's called each time a cell is being shown. If you update cell's textfield with your array of names there, it's done. :) You can try to read about how UITableView cells work, because I feel like that's the only thing you're missing. (specifically how those are being reused and updated with a content)